# Usage of the word "surge" in the following advertising slogan

Tags: meaning

I saw this slogan from a company called *Gett*. It says

> My mama don't like surge, and she likes everything. Our black cars never surge.

I know the word surge, but just to ensure if it means here a large increase in the number of cars coming to you?

Comment: My guess is: _"17. (Machinery) to move with pulsating unevenness, as something driven by an engine or gas turbine._ http://www.dictionary.com/browse/surge

Comment: BTW, why **don't** rather than **doesn't** do you guess? Grammatical mistake?@NVZ

Comment: _"My mama don't like you, and she likes everyone"_ is from a Justin Bieber song. See this [related ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/314939/50044) to learn more about the "don't" used here. In short, it's not grammatically correct, but grammar may not always work for song lyrics.

Comment: Gett appears to be a taxi firm, so it's probably referencing Uber's surge pricing  at busy times.

Comment: @JonLarby, so if this is true, that's what they mean without a doubt.

Comment: singular don't is pretty common in very informal North American dialects, not just lyrics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Surge* in this context is short for *surge pricing*, the feature of Uber that increases the cost of journeys during busy periods to encourage more of their drivers onto the road. Gett doesn't use surge pricing, which it considers unpopular, and so is using this in its advertising.

From [Uber Estimator](http://uberestimator.com/uber-surge-pricing) site:

> **Uber Surge Pricing**
>
> The Uber fare rates automatically increase, when the taxi demand is higher than drivers around you. The Uber prices are surging to ensure reliability and availability for those who agree to pay a bit more.

Comment: Aargh, the Uber notice uses a comma after *increase*.